# How do I enforce SAL annotations on a typedef'd function?

Tags: c, winapi, dll, sal

Let's say I import a DLL function like so:

```
typedef int(__stdcall *pRandomNumber)(size_t cb, unsigned char *pb);

HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibraryW(L"foo.dll");
pRandomNumber RandomNumber = (pRandomNumber)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "RandomNumber");
```

Now, this function `RandomNumber` in the code of the DLL is annotated with the SAL annotation `_Check_return_`. I also want to have this annotation enforced in code that calls it. How do I get that done?

If I put the annotation on the `typedef`:

```
_Check_return_
typedef int(__stdcall *pRandomNumber)(size_t cb, unsigned char *pb);
```

Analysis fails to report a warning later when I initialize a `pRandomNumber` and call it without checking the return value.

If I put the annotation on an instance:

```
typedef int(__stdcall *pRandomNumber)(size_t cb, unsigned char *pb);

_Check_return_
pRandomNumber RandomNumber;
```

Analysis still fails to report when I call it without checking the return value.

Is there any way I can have that enforced? One way is writing a stub inline function with the annotation on it, but that feels ugly to me.

Comment: I don't think you can enforce `_Check_return_` on a function type like that.  C++17 onward do have the [`[[nodiscard]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) attribute for the same purpose, but not sure if that can be applied to a function type, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of declare variable

```
int (__stdcall *pRandomNumber)(size_t cb, unsigned char *pb);
```

you can declare function with [`__declspec(dllimport)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dllexport-dllimport?view=msvc-160) attribute and use [`[[nodiscard]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) and/or [`_Must_inspect_result_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/annotating-function-behavior?view=msvc-160) on this declaration

```
EXTERN_C
_NODISCARD
DECLSPEC_IMPORT
_Must_inspect_result_
int 
WINAPI 
RandomNumber(
    _In_ size_t cb, 
    _Out_writes_bytes_(cb) unsigned char *pb
    );
```

internally, when you declare api with [`__declspec(dllimport)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/dllexport-dllimport?view=msvc-160) attribute, compiler [declare](https://dennisbabkin.com/blog/?t=intricacies-of-microsoft-compilers-part-2-__imp_-and-__imp_load_-prefixes) **variable** with `extern` keyword;

```
extern "C" { 
    extern PVOID __imp_<function_name>;
}
```

in place <function_name> [`__FUNCDNAME__`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-160) used - the decorated name of the function

so possible say and

```
extern PVOID __imp_##__FUNCDNAME__;
```

of course, because extern, this is only declaration. and if you not add definition - you got

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_RandomNumber
```

if you try call `RandomNumber`. so you need add definition. for `_AMD64_` this is very simply, because `extern "C"` symbols not decorated.

so simply write:

```
EXTERN_C_START
    PVOID __imp_RandomNumber;
EXTERN_C_END
```

instead

```
EXTERN_C_START
    int (__stdcall *pRandomNumber)(size_t cb, unsigned char *pb);
EXTERN_C_END
```

you need in both case declare pointer size variable, which will be hold function pointer - different only in name - you select `pRandomNumber` as name (and can select any name) - in my case - you must select `__imp_RandomNumber` ( `__imp_<function_name>` ) - add `__imp_` prefix to decorated function name.

but in case `_X86_` exist problem - for `__stdcall` - the **@** symbol will be in decorated function name. you need write

```
EXTERN_C_START
    PVOID __imp__RandomNumber@8;
EXTERN_C_END
```

because decorated name will be `_RandomNumber@8`. but `__imp__RandomNumber@8` not valid *c/c++* name. you can define such name in asm code but not in *c/c++*. but you can use `/alternatename` linker option.

```
__pragma(comment(linker, "/alternatename:__imp__RandomNumber@8=___imp_RandomNumber"))

EXTERN_C_START
    PVOID __imp_RandomNumber;
EXTERN_C_END
```

if linker not found `__imp__RandomNumber@8` it try use `___imp_RandomNumber` if it exist. and `__imp_RandomNumber` will be decorated to `___imp_RandomNumber` in *`_X86_`*

possible write next macro

```
#ifdef _X86_
#define ALT_NAME(name, n) __pragma(comment(linker, _CRT_STRINGIZE(/alternatename:__imp__##name##@##n####=___imp_##name)))
#else
#define ALT_NAME(name, n)
#endif

#define IMP_FUNC(name, n) EXTERN_C_START PVOID __imp_##name; EXTERN_C_END ALT_NAME(name, n)
```

with this you code will be

```
// global declaration

EXTERN_C
_NODISCARD
DECLSPEC_IMPORT
_Must_inspect_result_
int 
WINAPI 
RandomNumber(
    _In_ size_t cb, 
    _Out_writes_bytes_(cb) unsigned char *pb
    );

IMP_FUNC(RandomNumber, 8);

// initialization
__imp_RandomNumber = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"foo"), "RandomNumber");

//usage
if (__imp_RandomNumber )
{
    UCHAR test[16];
    RandomNumber(sizeof(test), test);
}
```

and you got

```
warning C4834: discarding return value of function with 'nodiscard' attribute
```

if not use return value of `RandomNumber`